# Java extends class as function argument

Tags: java

Not new to java, but this question bothers me. I think I do not have a solid foundation.

Let's say have classes `A`, `B`, `C` and `B extends A` and `C extends A`. My question is, how can I define a method `f()` so that it can take one of `List<A>`, `List<B>` and `List<C>` as argument?

Comment: It depends what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an upper-bounded wildcard:

```
f(List<? extends A> list)
```

See [Oracle's tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) for more information.

Note that this restricts you to only be able to get things out of the list in the method body; you can't call consumer methods on the list:

```
A item = list.get(0);  // OK.
list.add(new A());     // Not OK! list might be a List<B>.
```